# Azure Data Factory - How to initialize variable with null value

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am calling a stored procedure from the Azure Data Factory. And part of one parameter I need to pass `Null`. However, the problem is, if I set null, it takes `"Null"` as a string.

Is there a way I can initialize a variable with null?

Comment: Isn’t there a checkbox - “Treat as null”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a NULL value to a Stored Procedure from the Stored procedure activity using the "Treat as null" checkbox:
[image]

It seems that the real question though is how to set a Variable's value to NULL. The only way I can see right off the bat is to (mis)use the coalesce function:
[image]

NOTE: I have not tested this, so YMMV.

Comment: coalesce(null,null,null) store a null value

but then when I use the variable , it's transformed by a ""

an empty string